# using tkz-graph to draw concentric cycles of vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I would like to use `tkz-graph` to layout cycles of vertices on concentric circles.  If I had complete cycles then `tkz-berge` would do teh job nicely but because I wish to exclude some edges it seems to me that I need the former package.  I would like to be able to achieve something like the subfigure on the left (first tikzpicture environment) by means of the `tkz-graph`'s `\Vertices*` and `\Edges` macros.  Here is a failing MWE, I believe.

```
\documentclass{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,rotate=22.5]
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={minimum size=3pt}}
      \grCycle[RA=1.0,prefix=a,Math=true]{8}
      \grCycle[RA=2.5,prefix=b,Math=true]{8}
      \grCycle[RA=4.0,prefix=c,Math=true]{8}
      \grCycle[RA=5.5,prefix=d,Math=true]{8}
      \EdgeIdentity{a}{b}{8}
      \EdgeIdentity{b}{c}{8}
      \EdgeIdentity{c}{d}{8}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,rotate=18]
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={minimum size=3pt}}
      \tikzset{node distance = 1.5cm}
      \Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E}

      \begin{scope}
        \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={node distance = 3cm}}
%        \tikzstyle{every node} = [node distance = 3cm]
        \Vertices*{circle}{F,G,H,I,J}
      \end{scope}

      \begin{scope}
        \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={node distance = 4.5cm}}
%        \tikzstyle{every node} = [node distance = 3cm]
        \Vertices*{circle}{K,L,M,N,O}
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From what I have read the answer might be for me to use `\SetGraphUnit{1.5}` but for other reasons I do not want to upgrade my texlive installation to the latest one.  Is there a way I can layout vertices on concentric circles so that I can add only those edges I need?

Comment: I don't understand the link between the question and `\SetGraphUnit`? can you explain your idea ?

Comment: This was an idea that I had in desperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand your question but you can use `\grEmptyCycle` if you want cycle without edges.

Then you can mix macros from tkz-berge and tkz-graph. I don't understand the link between the question and `\SetGraphUnit`? this macro modifies the unit used to define the distance between the vertices.

```
\documentclass{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,rotate=22.5]
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={minimum size=3pt}}
      \grEmptyCycle[RA=1.0,prefix=a,Math=true]{8}
      \grEmptyCycle[RA=2.5,prefix=b,Math=true]{8}
      \grEmptyCycle[RA=4.0,prefix=c,Math=true]{8}
      \grEmptyCycle[RA=5.5,prefix=d,Math=true]{8}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarks : With tkz-berge there are some macros to draw sequences of edges like a0-a1-a2-a4 etc .. and you can exclude some edges.

It's possible to use a macro from tikz-graph. You can use the option circle with Vertice.

Comment: Thank you, this points me in the right direction.  What I had not known was that it is possible to index individual vertices in the cycle.  Now I can add edges as I want.  Merci bien :-).

Answer (score 2):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot,pgfmath}
\psset{plotpoints=9,showpoints}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\foreach \c[count=\r from 1] in {A,...,D}{\curvepnodes{0}{360}{\r\space t PtoC}{\c}\psnline(0,8){\c}}
\foreach \i in {0,...,8}{\psline(A\i)(B\i)(C\i)(D\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for typing exercise with `TiKZ` not for PSTricks may be :).